# BATCH: Escaping

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, escaping, findstr

Im trying to make simple batch file that would copy all lines with `width="10` string from **.htm** file to **.txt** but im stuck with doublequote `"` symbol in the string

My code:

`for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('FINDSTR /C:"width=\"10" "htmfile.htm"') do (echo %%g >> test.txt)`

---

`'FINDSTR /C:"width='` this is still working but when I add the `"`, its not working anymore. I added escaping `\"` and and also tryed `^"` but it is still not working.

---

I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first ensure that the `cmd.exe` parser sends the correct match string to `FindStr`, *i.e. `/C:"width=\""`*. To do that I'd suggest escaping the closing doublequote with the standard escape character, the caret, **`^`**.

I don't really see the purpose of the `For` loop, *(unless you're just trying to remove any leading whitespace)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
FindStr /C:"width=\"10^" "htmfile.htm" 2>Nul >"test.txt"
Pause
```

Because the content of the `For` parentheses are ran through another `cmd.exe` instance you'd need to escape the caret escape character with two more carets:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('FindStr /C:"width=\"10^^^" "htmfile.htm" 2^>Nul'
) Do (Echo %%A)>>"test.txt"
Pause
```

Comment: Ha, you beat me by some seconds, I was just typing the same... nice job!

Comment: Can even do it without the `/C` option. `findstr width=\"10 blah.htm`